# Bootstrap 4 row not center aligned

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap `row`, with 4 `columns` in it. Originally I had 3 columns with icons, and they all aligned perfectly. I added a fourth in, and now the new one I added is slightly further down the page than the rest. It just doesn't sit in line

```
<div class="col-12 padding">
    <h3>Also take a look at my Github, Free Code Camp, Team Treehouse and LinkedIn profiles!</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github icons"></i></a>
    <h4>GitHub</h4>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-free-code-camp icons"></i></a>
    <h4>Free Code Camp</h4>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fi-social-treehouse icons"></i></a>
    <h4>Team Treehouse</h4>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin icons"></i></a>
    <h4>LinkedIn</h4>
</div>
```

It's the third column (team treehouse) that doesn't sit in line with the rest.

Also, they are all within a row div, it's just not shown.

**EDIT:**

It seems the problem is 3 of the icons are from Font Awesome, and the Treehouse icon is from Foundation Icons. Now I know the problem, but im not sure how to fix it. They are all styled to the same size

Comment: It is look into one line. I think your code is right. can you please elaborate more?

Comment: So, all of the icons are in the same line. However the third icon, is like 20px (an estimate) lower than the rest. So #1, #2, #4 are all on the same straight line, and #3 is like 20px lower. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: maybe it has something to do with that icon 1,2 and 4. are from font awesome, and icon 3 is from foundation icons?

Comment: Yes, You are right.

Comment: The mark you posted doesn't demonstrate the issue and doesn't follow the Bootstrap "rule" that `col-*` must be placed inside `.row`. https://www.codeply.com/go/zUudE4Menz Also there is no longer `-xs` in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: That is because the codeply you ran, only includes the font awesome icons. As i have stated before... 3 icons are font awesome icons, and the Treehouse one is https://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icon-fonts-3. the problem is they are from different libraries, however I'm looking for a solution

Answer (score 1):

If you believe it is the icon, test your theory by adding a border to the icons class. This way you will be able to tell if the third icon is positioned oddly, or has padding built into the image itself. If that is the case copy the image and edit it to suit.

Or you can hack the offending icon with some CSS like so:

```
.fi-social-treehouse {
  margin-top: -20px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I checked inside the CSS sheet for Foundation Icons and compared it to the CSS sheet of Font Awesome, and couldn't find a difference. So I ended up hard coding a negative margin to the column that the treehouse icon is within. If anyone has a better solution, I would be happy to hear it!